# How can RSpec check that an argument object has one value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a function being called like

```
car.method({a: 3, b: 6, c: 9})
```

And in RSpec, I want to assert that b: 6 is called, but not any of the other values.

```
expect(car).to receive(:method).with({b: 6})
```

How can I do that without strictly matching the entire object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I right understand your question, it may write like this (from [relishapp.com](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments)):

`expect(car).to receive(:method).with(hash_including(b: 6))`

Anyway, see matching arguments from this source, it can help to resolve your problem.